# Transparency React Native With Expo

Tags: react-native, mobile

I have problems with the transparency of a View in React Native Expo, within the View I have text but this is not seen on iphone devices and on androids the text is seen with transparency but it is not what I want.

Code:

```
<View style= {{paddingHorizontal:30, borderRadius:1, marginTop:5}}>
        <View style={{alpha = 1.0, alignItems:'center', borderRadius:10, backgroundColor: 'white', alignContent:'center', paddingVertical:10}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:15, color:'white', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Iniciar Sesión</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
```

What I want to do:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPBsh.png)

What i get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjdKb.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `alpha` on the style is applied to the entire view and as a result also causes the all child components to become transparent. You want to apply your alpha only to the background color of the parent view. In react-native you can achieve that by defining your backgroundcolor rgba format

Color documentation can be found
https://reactnative.dev/docs/colors

And here is an expo snack to demonstrate the behavior.
https://snack.expo.io/sl8VafHil